# EPIServer mulit-language routing can't work

Tags: routes, episerver

I have two pages used same page type, the url like following

1. http://website/en/{node}/GUID
2. http://website/client/en/{node}/GUID (By the way, the 'client' will change for different language)

I created a router like this {language}/{node}/{id}/{action},but only link 1 works, link 2 is 404.

Could anyone give help about this to let link2 work?

I used EPIServer 8.2

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you registering the route using MapContentRoute? And if so, have you tried adding a route with a segment that matches the 'client' part, e.g. '{client}/{language}/{node}/{id}/{action}'?

Comment: @Henrik, thanks for your feedback. I used MapContentRoute and added  {client}/{language}/{node}/{id}/{action} like you said, but still can't work.

Comment: Perhaps you could try a route debugger (such as http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx/) to see if another matching route exists earlier in the route table?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because the {client} out of the start page , It should use MapPageRootRoute to add routes.